# Compare values in matlab and return the least value in a 1000x1 data array

Tags: matlab

I would like to know how I can come up with a function in matlab that can compare the data in a single column of data consisting of 1000 rows and return the least or maximum value of that column. The code I have written so far is shown below and is working fine

```
`load("MSposition_NoMS_100_NoSimStep_1000 (1).mat");

numCols = size(PosMS, 2);
numRows = size(PosMS, 1);
PosSBS_1 = [200 200];
PosSBS_2 = [200 800];
PosSBS_3 = [800 200];
PosSBS_4 = [800 800];

% Extract X-Y coordinate pairs with all 1000 rows
if mod(numCols, 2) ~= 0
    error('The number of columns must be even for this operation.');
end

% Initialize a cell array to store the X-Y coordinate pairs
coordinatePairs = cell(1, numCols/2);

% Loop to extract and store X-Y coordinate pairs with all 1000 rows
for i = 1:2:numCols
    % Extract the first column (X-coordinate) in the pair
    X = PosMS(:, i);
    
    % Extract the second column (Y-coordinate) in the pair
    Y = PosMS(:, i+1);
    
    % Combine X and Y columns into a pair and store it in the cell array
    coordinatePairs{(i+1)/2} = [X, Y];
end

% Now, "coordinatePairs" is a cell array containing X-Y coordinate pairs.
% Each element of the cell array is a 1000x2 matrix representing an X-Y coordinate pair with all 1000 rows.

% Create variables MsPOS1, MsPOS2, MsPOS3, and so on
for pairIndex = 1:length(coordinatePairs)
    variableName = ['MsPOS_', num2str(pairIndex)];
    eval([variableName, ' = coordinatePairs{pairIndex};']);
end

% Now, I have variables MsPOS1, MsPOS2, MsPOS3, and so on, each containing a pair of X-Y coordinates.
for Position_Pairs = 1:numRows

    Distance_MsPOS_1_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_1(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 1 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_1_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_1(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 1 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_1_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_1(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 1 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_1_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_1(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 1 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_2_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_2(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_2(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 2 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_2_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_2(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_2(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 2 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_2_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_2(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_2(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 2 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_2_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_2(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_2(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 2 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_3_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_3(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_3(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 3 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_3_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_3(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_3(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 3 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_3_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_3(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_3(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 3 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_3_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_3(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_3(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 3 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_4_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_4(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 4 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_4_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_4(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 4 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_4_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_4(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 4 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_4_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_4(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_1(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 4 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_5_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_5(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_5(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 5 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_5_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_5(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_5(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 5 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_5_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_5(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_5(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 5 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_5_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_5(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_5(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 5 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_6_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_6(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_6(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 6 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_6_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_6(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_6(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 6 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_6_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_6(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_6(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 6 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_6_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_6(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_6(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 6 and Static base station 4
    
    Distance_MsPOS_7_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_7(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_7(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 7 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_7_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_7(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_7(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 7 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_7_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_7(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_7(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 7 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_7_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_7(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_7(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 7 and Static base station 4
    
    Distance_MsPOS_8_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_8(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_8(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 8 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_8_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_8(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_8(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 8 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_8_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_8(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_8(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 8 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_8_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_8(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_8(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 8 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_9_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_9(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_9(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 9 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_9_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_9(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_9(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 9 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_9_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_9(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_9(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 9 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_9_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_9(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_9(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 9 and Static base station 4

    Distance_MsPOS_10_1 = sqrt((MsPOS_10(:,1)-PosSBS_1(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_10(:,2)-PosSBS_1(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 10 and Static base station 1
    Distance_MsPOS_10_2 = sqrt((MsPOS_10(:,1)-PosSBS_2(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_10(:,2)-PosSBS_2(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 10 and Static base station 2
    Distance_MsPOS_10_3 = sqrt((MsPOS_10(:,1)-PosSBS_3(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_10(:,2)-PosSBS_3(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 10 and Static base station 3
    Distance_MsPOS_10_4 = sqrt((MsPOS_10(:,1)-PosSBS_4(:,1)).^2+(MsPOS_10(:,2)-PosSBS_4(:,2)).^2); % Distance between mobile base station 10 and Static base station 4
  
end
```

The variable PoSBS is a 1000*2 matrix and is the reference point for calculating the various distances of the variables MsPOS from it. I would like to know if there is a way to compare the data calculated in the Distance_MsPOS function and have it return the lowest or maximum value as well as get the corresponding rows in the previous calculation.

Comment: I don’t see a `Distance_MsPOS` function in your code. I do see a whole lot of `Distance_MsPOS_*_*` arrays created. You should never create so many variables with numbers attached. It’s a really good indication that instead you want to use `Distance_MsPOS{i,j}`, or maybe even `Distance_MsPOS(i,j)`, instead. Once all your data is in a single numeric array, use `max` and `min` to get the maximal and minimal values from it, and their location.

Comment: Thanks, how can I add this piece of code Distance_MsPOS{i,j} into the code rather than creating so many arrays?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, how can I add this piece of code Distance_MsPOS{i,j} into the code rather than creating so many arrays?

Comment: @NchimunyaMuyuni see [Alternatives to the eval function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) in MATLAB's documentation for some hints.